# `Anchor build`: failed to select a version for the requirement `rust_decimal = "..."

Tags: anchor, cargo

Both `anchor build` and `cargo build-bpf` fail with:

```
BPF SDK: /home/fish/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.29/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `rust_decimal = "^1.27.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 1.26.1, 1.26.0, 1.25.0, ...
```

However

(1) rust_decimal is the correct library and latest version (`cargo search rust_decimal` shows 1.27.0)

(2) There is no version conflict with another dependency

(3) Rejects wildcard version too with the same error (e.g. `rust_decimal = "*")

(4) `rustup update` already attempted, cleared rust cache by deleting ~cargo/registry/index

(5) Any project that doesn't use rust_decimal can build just fine.

Is there a problem with rust_decimal or something up with my setup?

Ubuntu Linux, cargo version 1.65.0, anchor 0.24.2, solana 1.9.29

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug due to the solana version: updating to 1.14 fixed it. Somewhere around 1.11 there was an update to the way cargo-bpf is called, and cargo build-bpf is no longer the normal build toolpath.